# gatsby-source-graphql only absolute urls are supported

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm integrating graphQL into my gatsby site. I am getting an error that says "only absolute urls are supported" and then points to some code in the node-fetch library. There isn't an obvious path to how I'm getting that code to execute though, so I'm not sure what the source of my issue is. I have done several days worth of searching, and while I have found several threads about this error, it's never been in the context of gatsby-source-graphql. Any help would be appreciated.

package.json

```
{
  .
  .
  .
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.9.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.9.0",
    "fullcalendar-reactwrapper": "^1.0.7",
    "gatsby": "^2.12.0",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.7.20",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "^4.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.6",
    "gatsby-source-graphql": "^2.1.3",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.9",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "netlify-cms-app": "^2.9.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-calendar": "^2.17.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.21.0"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  "devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "material-icons-react": "^1.0.4",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.9.2",
    "surge": "^0.20.1"
  },
  .
  .
  .
}
```

UpcomingScheduleChanges.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

import Cancellations from './Cancellations';

class UpcomingScheduleChanges extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.cancellations)
        return (
            <div className="col-6">
                <header className="major">
                    <h2>Upcoming Schedule Changes</h2>
                </header>
                {this.props.cancellations ? (
                    <Cancellations cancellations={this.props.cancellations}></Cancellations>
                ) : (
                    <p>There are no upcomimng schedule changes!</p>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default () => (
    <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
        query ScheduleChanges {
            allMarkdownRemark {
            edges {
              node {
                  frontmatter {
                  cancellation {
                    date(formatString: "MMMM DD")
                    day
                    location
                    type
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        `}
        render={(data) => <UpcomingScheduleChanges cancellations={data.allMarkdownRemark.edges[0].node.frontmatter.cancellation} />}
    />
);
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

import Layout from "../components/layout";

import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";
import ContactForm from "../components/ContactForm";
import Schedule from '../components/Schedule';
import Welcome from "../components/Welcome";
import Administrators from "../components/Administrators";
import MailingList from "../components/MailingList";

class Homepage extends React.Component {
    handleClick(url) {
        window.open(url, "_blank");
    }

    render() {
        const siteTitle = "...";

        return (
            <Layout>
                <Helmet title={siteTitle}>
                    <script src="https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js"></script>
                </Helmet>

                <Welcome></Welcome>

                <Schedule></Schedule>

                <Administrators></Administrators>

                <MailingList></MailingList>

                <ContactForm></ContactForm>

                <ReactTooltip />

                <script>
                    {`if (window.netlifyIdentity) {
                        window.netlifyIdentity.on("init", user => {
                            if (!user) {
                                window.netlifyIdentity.on("login", () => {
                                    document.location.href = "/admin/";
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }`}
                </script>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default Homepage;
```

gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "...",
    author: "...",
    description: "..."
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: '...',
        short_name: '...',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#FFFFFF',
        theme_color: '#FFFFFF',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/assets/images/banner_small.png', // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    'gatsby-transformer-remark',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/static/content`,
        name: 'content'
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        typeName: "cancellations",
        fieldName: "cancellations",
        url: `${__dirname}/static/content/cancellations.md`
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-offline',
    'gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms'
  ],
}
```

config.yml

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master #branch to update (optional; defaults to master)
publish_mode: editorial_workflow #allows for a drafting, reviewing, and approving process for changes
media_folder: "src/assets/images/uploads"
public_folder: "/images"

#collections
collections:
  - label: "Upcoming Schedule Changes"
    name: "upcoming schedule changes"
    files:
      - label: "Cancellations"
        name: "cancellations"
        file: "static/content/cancellations.md"
        fields:
        - label: "Cancellations"
          name: "cancellations"
          create: true
          widget: "list"
          fields:
            - {label: "Date", name: "date", widget: "date"}
            - {label: "Day", name: "day", widget: "select", options: ["Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday"]}
            - {label: "Location", name: "location", widget: "select", options: ["Location1", "Location2", "Location3"]}
            - {label: "Type", name: "type", widget: "select", options: ["Cancelled", "Delayed", "Relocated"]}
```

Comment: Did you try changing this `url: \`${__dirname}/static/content/cancellations.md\`` to an absolute url?

Comment: From what I've read on other threads, node-fetch (the package throwing the error) wants a url to being with http:// or https:// for it to be considered absolute. There isn't a url with that format that I can provide that I know of that will provide access to that file.

Comment: Are you just trying to source data from some local markdown files? If so, I would not bother with `gatsby-source-graphql`

Comment: @ksav, yes. What's the recommended method? Sorry for the delay...

Comment: I think you only need `gatsby-transformer-remark`, and `gatsby-source-filesystem` to source from local markdown files. If you want a quick start project, take a look at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/

Comment: Thanks @ksav! I literally just removed the graphQL plug in and all was dandy!